# Why isn't $\{(1,1),(1,2),(2,1)\}$ transitive relation?

Tags: relations

As we knows that
Transitive relation R is 
(a, b) € R and 
(b, c) € R implies
(a, c) € R

So we can suppose that 
let a be 1 and b be 2 and c be 1 
Then, 
(a, b) € R **means** (1,2) € R and 
(b, c) € R **means** (2,1) € R implies
(a, c) € R **means** (1,1) € R

Then it must be transitive
.... But why isn't? 
Plz plz tell me fastly

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Maybe because $(2,2)$ is not in your set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to be a transitive relation on some set X, R has to satisfy:
$$a\text{R}b \quad \text{and} \quad b\text{R}c \quad \Rightarrow \quad a\text{R}c, \quad \text{for each} \quad a,b,c \in X.$$

In your example, we can take $a=2, b=1, c= 2$, and it is obvious that $a$ is in relation with $b$ and that $b$ is in relation with $c$. But, it is also obvious that $a$ is **not** in relation with $c$, so your relation is not transitive.

Comment: Hey buddy but we can also take a =1, b = 2 and c = 1,then we gotta our tran. Relation

Comment: To @5Dots : an accent is on **for each** $a,b,c \in X$...

Comment: The constraint must hold *for all* $a$, $b$, and $c$.  Thus the relation is not transitive if *there exists* a counter example: where $(a R b)\wedge (b R c) \wedge \neg(a R c)$. $$(2 R 1)\wedge(1 R 2)\wedge\neg(1 R 1)$$

Answer (score 0):

The relation isn't transitive because while $(2, 1), (1, 2)$ are in the relation, $(2, 2)$ is not.